# Avatarams of God

Tags: vishnu, puranas, avatars, venkateshwara

Lord Ranganatha of srirangam or srirangapatna  and Lord Venkatachalapathy of Tirupati are not coming under ten  Avatars of God Vishnu. Why is it so? Any reference from puranas will be of great help to understand.

Comment: First of all, the Dasavatharam is not a comprehensive list of all the avatarams of Vishnu, it's just a "top ten" list.  Vishnu has had countless avatarams.  Second of all, in Pancharatra philosophy, Vishnu has five kinds of manifestations: Para, Vyuha, Vibhava, Antaryami and Archa. See here for details: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pancharatra#Divine_Manifestation The Ranganatha statue falls under Archa, whereas Avatarams fall under Vibhava.

Comment: From Wikipedia anybody can refer. I have gone and then only asked the question. The manifestations I have read  in the wiki itself and know thru Vishnu  purana. I needed an advance thought for this. You have not mentioned abt Lord venkatachalapathy.